# How to implement indexing in codeigniter3 with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter-3, cpanel

I have codeIgniter3 project and db used is MongoDB. All the connections and CRUD operations are working fine with MongoDB. Implementing indexing via controller/model is not working. Indexing via mongoshell/terminal is working (tried all things in cPanel)

I have tried with these codes (tested both in controller and models) . But not working

```
$this->mongo_db->createIndex('collectionName', array('field1' => 1));
```

```
$options = array('background' => true);
$this->mongo_db->create_index('dbName','collectionName', array("field1" => 1, "field2" => 1), $options);
```

```
$this->mongo_db->create_index('collectionName', array("field1" => 1, "field2" => 1), $options);
```

tried these three methods both in controller and models but none works

Error message is  : **Call to undefined method Mongo_db::createIndex()**
**Call to undefined method Mongo_db::create_index()**